# Salesforce External user Custom Login and registration using apex

Tags: user-management

I am working on developing custom salesforce app (Survey app) in salesforce, things so far i have done are.
Add survey 
Add Survey Questions
Making the survey Link Public.
Take Survey
Survey Result etc.

Public Survey Link is here: 
https://lycore-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/TakeSurvey?id=a012800000ISuXc

Now i need to know that how can i Create a custom Login and Custom registration for an external user(Could be anyone), so, before taking the survey, users could login or Register themselves into salesforce. I need the way to Login or register.

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom login and registration beyond Salesforce platform users breaks TOS of Salesforce and can lead to legal issues in future. So I highly recommend you to use the out of the box Salesforce user management for this

> Possible duplicate of [Is there any session objects in salesforce ?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/110431/3672)

Comment: So, we cannot create/register user on public websites in salesforce for non salesforce users at all unless they have salesforce license am i right ? @karthikselva